# $\cup A_n$ is infinite and has infinite complement

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

This is exercise 1.1.9 in Friedman's "Foundations of Modern Analysis":

> Let $\mathscr{D}$ consist of those sets [in $2^X$?] which are either finite or have a finite complement... If $X$ is not finite, then $\mathscr{D}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Now, $\mathscr{D}$ is an algebra, so I figure this comes down to showing that if $A_n \in \mathscr{D}$ ($n=1,2,...$) then $\cup A_n$ is neither finite nor has finite complement. Problem is I don't know how to do this in an effective way. I've tried breaking the problem up ("suppose the $A_n$ are finite" etc) but there are too many subcases, which in themselves are probably more difficult than the original question. I'm sure this result follows immediately from one crucical observation, I just don't know what it is. So I would appreciate a hint with this one, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First try to write down some set which is not in $\mathscr{D}$, then think about whether it could be a countable union of sets in $\mathscr{D}$.

Don't forget that you only need to find one example where the condition fails.  Don't stress yourself out considering general cases.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to think of a general infinite set whose complement is not finite :P But your answer was insightful. However I'm not sure about only needing to find an example. I interpret the assertion that it is always the case that $\mathscr{D}$ is not a sigma algebra when $X$ is infinite. Otherwise wouldn't it have said "then there exists an infinite set $X$ such that $\mathscr{D}$ is not a sigma algebra"?

Comment: @ErikVesterlund Yes, you're right.  What is I mean is that you only need to find one countable  union of sets in $\mathscr{D}$ which is not in $\mathscr{D}$.

But you should still try to tackle one particular infinite $X$ before you go after the general case.  How about $X=\mathbb{N}$?  Can you find an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ whose compliment is also infinite?

Comment: @ErikVesterlund (and it will turn out that every other case reduces to that one, so in a way, you really do just need to solve one case)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $X$ is infinite, partition it into two infinite subsets $X_0$ and $X_1$. Let $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countably infinite subset of $X_0$, and consider the sets $A_n=\{x_n\}$. (The existence of the desired partition does require some part of the axiom of choice, but I take that for granted.)

Comment: Doing measure theory without at least countable choice, if not dependent choice, is nothing short but self abuse.

Comment: @Asaf: You’ll get no argument from me! Same for topology: I *like* my Tikhonov theorem, thank you very much!

Comment: Of course. I do support, of course, the research into how much of a self abuse it is to do these things without the axiom of choice, though. ;-)

Comment: @Asaf: I’ve no problem at all with that, either; I just get a bit puzzled when people worry about it in an ‘everyday’ mathematical setting.

Comment: I know that you don't have an issue with that. I also agree with your opinion, and despite the image I managed to create myself, I have strong opinions in favor of the axiom of choice outside of set theory. I do support, however, knowing your foundations better and understanding when you appeal to certain properties (like when you point out when you are using continuity, or separation axioms) and I do think that we should learn to recognize the places where we use the axiom of choice better; but I share the utilitarian point of view here, it's more than reasonable to just assume choice today.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm not sure how I could partition the set. But suppose $X_0$ and $A_n$ are as you define them. Then the countable union of the $A_n$ equals $X_0$, which is infinite, and its complement is infinite, qed. Question is if this can be done (I guess this is what you mean by AC). Well suppose $X = \{\ x_i \mid i \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ and $X_0 = \{ x_i \in X \mid i \in (2) \}$. This is a legal example.

Comment: @Erik: The business with the axiom of choice has to do with axiomatic set theory. One of the axioms of the standard axiomatization is the axiom of choice, which implies that you can always do it, no matter what non-finite set $X$ you have. This axiom has some other consequence that have caused some people to prefer not to accept it, or at least to mention it explicitly when it’s used; my comment was a sop for such people. Withough AC it’s consistent to have a non-finite $X$ that cannot be partitioned into two infinite sets.